# How to add attachments from Flask to win32com?

Tags: python, flask, pywin32, win32com

Hi I am having trouble attaching flask uploads to Outlook,

I need to attach uploads from flask to outlook.

Thanks

'''        f = rq.files['filesattach']

```
    msg.HTMLBody = str("<br> <br>Hi, the follow data are attached to this email <br>").title() + "\n \n" + "<br> Date Request Sent to Permit Coordinator: " + dateReq + "\n" + "<br>WO #: "+ wo+ " \n" + "<br>Date Needed: " + dateNeed + "\n" +"<br>SR: "+ sr + "\n" + "<br>TCF: " +tcf + "\n" + "<br>Munplicity: "+ mun + "\n" + "<br>Political Sub: " + polSub + "\n" + '<br>Address: '+ address + "\n" + '<br>Cross Street: ' + cross + "\n" + '<br>Description: '+ desc + "\n" + "<br>Permit Type: " + permitType
    msg.Subject = "WO " + wo +" "+ permitType+" "+"Permit Form"
    msg.Display()
    shell.AppActivate("Outlook")
    shell.SendKeys("%s", 0)

    saved = f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))

    return "Message sent"
else:
    return render_template(permitForm)'''
```

Comment: what does outlook have to do with anything... you should be using a mailserver to send mail ... ...

Comment: company does not provide server port, that is why.... don't worry about what it has to do with anything it is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
    uploaded_files = rq.files.getlist("filesattach")
    
    for i in uploaded_files:
        file = os.path.realpath(str(i.filename))
        msg.attachments.Add(file)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.